# Can I import version history from Serena into Team Foundation Server?

Tags: tfs, serena

I'm really asking this on behalf of our sysadmins, so here goes:

We are moving from Serena to Team Foundation Server as our source code repository. It's a done deal (for better or worse) and I'm already aware of "no keyword expansion".

Anyway, the admins are planning to import source as version 1.0 (or whatever it uses for the first one) and forget about the history in Serena. However, it's a very large and fairly old codebase, and the loss of version history means losing a lot of information.

I have a fallback position of generating an ASCII version history files, one per module, and trying to attach them to each module in TFS. I'd much rather find a way to slam the version history in and preserve the version numbering (or something like it) once we're in TFS.

Comment: FWIW, we're trying to do exactly the same thing (in what sounds like identical circumstances - uncanny) and we have no good answer either. There's no export route from Serena Dimensions that I know of. My impression is that the kind of process-driven and risk-averse company that uses Dimensions is not the kind of company that would ever consider releasing an export tool to the developer community at large, and Serena certainly have no interest in doing so. My plan is manually to GET every baseline and book these into TFS in chronological order. File renames and deletes will be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

[Not answering the asked question] There's a CodePlex project out there that inserts keyword expansion to the TFS check-in process if you really want it.  We use this with our SQL & PowerBuilder code and it seems to work well if you can accept a particular idiosyncrasy.

The project is [Log Substitution Policy](http://logsubstpol.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool for migration PVCS source control data to TFS:
http://www.pvcs2tfs.com/

Comment: Have you used this tool? Does it work well? Do you know how much it costs? There doesn't seem to be much information on the website.

Comment: @Tom: Yes, we are the developer of the product ;) / what info do you miss at the website? You can request a demo version...